# Why can't I assign this int a value?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, int, variable-assignment

I have a class:

```
    class A
    {
    public:
        A();
        ~A();

        void IncrementNum();

    private:
        int num;
    };

    A::A() : num(0)
    {

    }

    A::~A()
    {
    }

    void A::IncrementNum()
    {
        num++;
    }

    int main()
    {
        A obj;
        obj.IncrementNum();
    }
```

When I set a breakpoint in the constructor, it shows that num is equal to some random value (such as -2483290483), which I take as meaning it's unassigned.  And sure enough, when I call IncerementNum(), and set a breakpoint on the line after `num++`, it shows the exact same thing (num equals some random number).  Repeated calls to IncrementNum() do not change anything, num doesn't change.

So I decided to instead change `num++` to `num = 1`, thinking surely this would force `num` to be set.  Nope.  `num` still shows as being some random number even after discretely setting it to 1.  Again, successive calls to the new version of IncrementNum() fail to change its value.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Other info:

I'm using Windows 7 Home Edition and Visual Studio 2010

Comment: If you cut and paste this exactly then you have a typo as in I[m]crementNum() but I think that's not the case in your actual code, it wouldn't compile :) Should I fix it?

Comment: Please use real code. You don't get typos in the middle of identifiers from copy-pasting code that exhibits your problem.

Comment: Sorry the real code is much larger and more obnoxious to look at than this.  Spook already answered the question (I just have to wait till i can accept it)

Comment: @xcdemon05, In the future, then, http://sscce.org.

Comment: That's what I was going for, I just botched the CC on accident.  Noted for next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably compiling it in Release mode. The Compiler sees that `num` is not being used anywhere and optimized it out. Try to display `num` with `printf()` or `cout` and try the test again.